# Combine independent scores to make aggregate score in duplicate detection algorithm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scoring

I'm building a duplicate detector, and I have identified a few factors that should be correlated to being a duplicate:

- Comparison of document lengths
- Comparison of document titles
- Comparison of document citations
- Comparison of document texts using "[gestalt pattern matching](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio)"

I can easily get a 0-1 value for any of these factors, but where I'm stuck is how to combine these factors into an aggregate.

So, for example, if the length is spot on and the titles are very similar, I can probably assume it's a duplicate, even if the citation is fairly different, because citations are messy in this corpus. Or you can imagine similar kinds of things (length is off, but other factor are on; all factors are good but not great; etc).

Ultimately what I'd like to do is have the system identify documents that might be duplicates (this part is easy), and then I say yay or nay. As I vote on these duplicates, it determines what kinds of scores should be expected in a valid duplicate, and learns how to proceed without my yays or nays.

Comment: Sorry, I don't figure out what is your _question_.

Comment: You need fuzzy comparisons, which are dependent on the heuristics of your domain. Without knowing much about your domain, it'll be VERY difficult 9at least for me) to say anything useful here

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the gestalt pattern matching is a form of fuzzy matching. What I want is to combine that with other factors like document length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some kind of machine learning [classification algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_in_machine_learning) that uses your inputs as features.

That is, what you're asking for is a black-box function that takes a 0-1 score for each of those factors and gives you an overall score as to whether the document pair should be considered a duplicate. You need to choose such a function based on a list of (input, output) pairs, where the inputs are those four features from above (or whatever other ones you think might make sense) and the outputs are either 0 (not duplicate) or 1 (duplicate).

This is exactly the standard setting for classification. Some options for accomplishing this include [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), [decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning), [neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), [support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), and many many more.

Logistic regression might be a good choice; it's fairly easy and quick to implement but also quite powerful. Basically, it chooses weights to assign to each dimension based on the training data, and then predicts by adding up the weighted features and passing that sum through a logistic function `1/(1+exp(sum))` to give a probability of being a duplicate. This amounts to selecting a separating hyperplane in the 4-dimensional space chosen by your features: if the 4-dimensional input point lies on one side it's positive, on the other side it's negative.

If you want a simple numpy implementation to look at for reference, [here's one](http://db.tt/UH1yGjr5) that I wrote for a class assignment.

---

Note that this approach only tells you what to do for a pairwise comparison: unless your number of documents is quite small, you probably won't want to do this for every pair of documents (since the fuzzy content matching at least is probably fairly expensive to compute, though with logistic regression the actual prediction is fairly easy). You'll probably have to come up with some heuristic for deciding which documents to consider as duplicates at all (based on, say, a nearest-neighbors title search or citation matching or TF-IDF scores or something).

Comment: Awesome answer -- it's going to take me some time to absorb. Just looked at your resume, and I'm convinced you sit around on SO just waiting for questions like this one. I'm indeed using TF-IDF to find likely duplicates as my first step (using Solr).

Comment: OK, two questions: 1) Why not use a Bayes classifier like [this one](https://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html)? 2) Know of any documented libraries for the linear regression technique (yours aside)?

Comment: Naïve Bayes is bad for your problem because it assumes that all the features are independent: for example, two documents having similar titles makes them no more or less likely to have similar texts. This is clearly very false for your problem. Now, you could do a full Bayes classifier (which means throwing away the assumption that your features are independent of each other). This expressive freedom means that fitting the model requires more data: effectively, you need to fit a model for each of the 2^4=16 combinations of input classes: probably okay with 4 features but not with many more.

Comment: There's apparently a [logistic regression implementation in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression). I haven't used it and have no idea of its quality. [This blog post](http://blog.smellthedata.com/2009/06/python-logistic-regression-with-l2.html) also has a description of the algorithm and an implementation of L2-regularized logistic regression (which basically means adding some additional constraints to avoid "overfitting" to the noise in the training set).

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is a *data model*--i.e., how to configure your data for input to a ML algorithm.

Here's one way to do it--there are likely other ways to do it, but i know this will work:

***Step 1***: *map each column in your data set* (e..g, document length) *to a value in a continuous variable or a 'factor' in a discrete variable*. For instance, 'document length' could be represented as 'total words'. The others mentioned in the OP are less straightforward but still not difficult, e.g., "citations" could be represented by a bitarray. This is a common pattern for handling data of this type in ML pre-processing. In particular, you gather all citations from all of the documents in an array, get the unique values from that array, which represents all citations in all of the articles. The length of that set of unique values is the length of your bit array. So for the first document, if citation #1 is present, then the offset at index 0 (the first item in the bitarray) is set to "1" (i.e., you call "setbit" on that bit array at index 0).

***Step 2:*** consider removing columns comprised of data *derived from* the other columnns; non-orthogonal features likely will just confuse your classifier; e.g., get rid of the "gestalt pattern matching"

***Step 3:*** the crux: **create the transformed data set by pair-wise, end-to-end *concatenation* of each document's data vector with with every other document's vector;** if you have 100 documents, then you will have 100^2 vectors in your transformed data set (the data actually fed to the classifier):

```
>>> d1 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]    
>>> d2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

>>> d12 = d1 + d2
```

***Step 4:*** ***add the class labels*** (to the end of each of the concatenated vector pairs in your tarnsformed data); in other words, if the two documents are a match, append a "1" to the end of the vector; if no match, then append "0". Thus the transformed data is comprised of n ^ 2 data vectors (n is the size of the original data set), in which each vector is an end-to-end concatenation of two data vectors from the original set plus a class label.

```
>>> d12 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

suppose the document pair represented by d12 is deemed a match, so then:

```
>>> class_label_d12 = [1]  

>>> d12 += class_label_d12

>>> d12
     [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

***Step 5***: Now your data is in the ordinary form for input to a supervised classifier. Select a supervised classifier (e.g., MLP, Decision Tree) and pass it your training data.

Comment: I wish I could give both of you the points for answering, cause both answers are really helpful. Went with @Dougal's answer though since I especially needed help understanding which classifier to use. Thanks though. This is proving helpful too.